# Writing console output to a file - file is unexpectedly empty

Tags: powershell, file-io, pipeline

I'm new to scripting and I am trying to write the information returned about a VM to a text file.  My script looks like this:

```
Connect-VIServer -Server 192.168.255.255 -Protocol https -User xxxx -Password XXXXXX

Get-VM -Name xxxxxx 

Get-VM xxxxx | Get-HardDisk | Select Parent, Name, Filename, DiskType, Persistence | FT -AutoSize 

Out-File -FilePath C:Filepath
```

I am able to connect to the VM, retrieve the HDD info and see it in the console.  The file is created where I want it and is correctly named.  No data is ever put into the file.  I have tried Tee-Object with the same results.  I've also tried the -append switch.  I did see a post about the data being returned as an array and Powershell is not able to move the data from an array to a string.  Do I need to create a variable to hold the returned data and write to file from there?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at `Tee-Object` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-6 it can do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
Get-VM xxxxx |
 Get-HardDisk |
   Select Parent, Name, Filename, DiskType, Persistence |
     Out-File -FilePath C:\Filepath
```

Answer (score 6):

[Guenther Schmitz' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55102058/45375) is effective, but it's worth explaining why:

- Your `Out-File -FilePath C:Filepath` is a *stand-alone* command that receives *no input*.

  - An `Out-File` call with no input simply creates an *empty file* (`0` bytes).
- **In order for cmdlets such as `Out-File` to receive input from (an)other command(s) (represented as `...` below), you must use the [*pipeline*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines)**, which means that you must place a `|` after the input command(s) and follow it with your `Out-File` call:
  <sup>Note that I'm using the shorter `-Path` parameter alias for the less commonly used `-FilePath`<sup>[1]</sup></sup>

  ```
  ... | Out-File -Path C:Filepath
  ```

  - In the simplest case, as above, the entire command (pipeline) is placed on the *same line*; if you want to spread it across multiple lines for readability, you have have two choices:

    - Put a line break immediately after `|`, which tells PowerShell that the command continues on the next line:

      ```
      ... |
        Out-File -Path C:Filepath
      ```
    - End a line with an explicit line continuation, which means placing `` ` `` at the *very end* of a line:

      ```
      ... `
      | Out-File -Path C:Filepath
      ```

Alternatively, since you're using `Out-File` with its default behavior, you could use `>`, an output redirection, instead:

```
... > C:Filepath
```

---

A couple of asides:

- Using `Out-File` with something other than strings, and using `Format-*` cmdlets in general, means that the output is only suitable for *display* (human consumption), not for further *programmatic processing*.
- If you want to send output to *both* the console *and* a file, use the [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object) cmdlet, as [TobyU](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10071078/tobyu) suggests:

  ```
  ... | Tee-Object -Path C:Filepath
  ```

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, `-LiteralPath` is the best choice in this case, because `-Path` interprets its arguments as wildcard expressions. However, omitting `-Path`, i.e. specifying the file path as a *positional* argument, as is common, implicitly binds to `-Path`.</sup>